# At what age could you hold custody of another in 12th century England?

Tags: middle-ages, europe, england, law

My question is as stated in the title. My reason for asking is that I know *girls* could marry at twelve, and boys at fourteen. I am wondering at what age could each have legal custody of another?

I would assume girls could at twelve because of children, but what about boys? What I mean by custody is like how a parent had custody over their child. If someone’s parents died, and they had little siblings, could the little siblings stay with them, or would they go to someone else?

I mean this as who might say, have the authority to apprentice someone, or approve a marriage proposal, or things like that.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by custody.  A noble had custody over his serfs. A man didn't have full rights until he had a title or property.  And I won't touch the question of "custody" over women.

Comment: Fixed it. @MarkC.Wallace.

Comment: Are you, perhaps, asking about [wardship](http://steventill.com/2010/09/03/medieval-history-term-of-the-week-wardship/)?

Comment: @sempaiscuba YES! I didn’t know there was a special term. Though I am asking about non gentry.

Comment: @TanzaniteDragoness The rights of a feudal lord applied to non-gentry as well The disposal of minors would still be in the Lord's gift.